# у меня не работает нормально реферальная система в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

у меня не работает нормально реферальная система в телеграмм боте. У меня в бд записывается id пользователя и когда по его силке заходит новый пользователь то к нему привязывается реферал. И у меня это в базу данных нормально записывается. Но когда я подсчитать сколько рефералов у пользователя, то всегда показывается ноль, но к новому пользователю записался айди пользователя кого тот пользователь пригласил, я уже все перепробовал, но все равно показывает ноль

```
main.py
import logging
import markups as nav
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from db import Database
import config as cfg

bot = Bot(token=cfg.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('database.db')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            start_command = message.text
            referrer_id = str(start_command[7:])
            if str(referrer_id) != "":
                if str(referrer_id) != str(message.from_user.id):
                    db.add_user(message.from_user.id, referrer_id)
                    try:
                        await bot.send_message(referrer_id, "По вашей силке зарегистрировался реферал")
                    except:
                        pass 
                else:
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "По своей силке нельзя")
            else: 
                db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Добро пожаловать", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
     if message.chat.type == 'private':
         if message.text == "Профиль":
             await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"ID: {message.from_user.id}\nhttps://t.me/{cfg.BOT_NICKNAME}?start={message.from_user.id}\nКількість рефералів: {db.count_reeferals(message.from_user.id)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)





db.py
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.create_table()

    def create_table(self):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("""
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' (
                    'user_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    'referrer_id' INTEGER
                )
            """)

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id, referrer_id=None):
        with self.connection:
            if not self.user_exists(user_id):
                if referrer_id != None:
                    return self.cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'users' ('user_id', 'referrer_id') VALUES (?,?)", (user_id, referrer_id))
                else:
                    return self.cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def count_reeferals(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT('id') as count FROM 'users' WHERE 'referrer_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()[0]



markups.py
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

mainMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
btnProfile = KeyboardButton("Профиль")
mainMenu.add(btnProfile)
```

Comment: А записи в БД есть? Может нет соответствия вот и 0 выводит

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаёте таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' ('user_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'referrer_id' INTEGER)
```

Но в этой строчке Вы подсчитываете столбец id
`SELECT COUNT('id') as count FROM 'users'`, хотя в таблице **users** нет такого столбца.

Исправьте на `SELECT COUNT('user_id') as count FROM 'users'`

Comment: Не сработало почему-то( может как-то переработать реферальную систему